# Questions with cash register program in windows forms app

Tags: c#

I am creating a cash register program. It is simple math where the results are > money paid - price. I want textbox to print out how much money you get back and in what denomination. So for instance, you enter price "500" and the cost "650" > Text should say "Money back: 150, 100 dollarbill
50 dollarbill". This is my first time programming in windows forms, I have already created the program in C# but cannot manage to figure it out on windows forms. My code looks like this.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int price, cost, tot, fivehundred, twohundred, onehundred, fifty, twenty;

    private void txt_two_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        price = Convert.ToInt32(txt_one.Text);
        cost = Convert.ToInt32(txt_two.Text);
        tot = cost - price;

        fivehundred = (cost - price) / (500);
        fivehundred = fivehundred % 500;

        twohundred = (cost - price) / 200;
        twohundred = twohundred % 200;

        onehundred = (cost - price) / 100;
        onehundred = onehundred % 100;

        fifty = (cost - price) / 50;
        fifty = fifty % 50;

        twenty = (cost - price) / 20;
        twenty = twenty % 20;

        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString("Money back: " + Environment.NewLine + tot + " dollar " + Environment.NewLine + (fivehundred) + " fivehundred" + Environment.NewLine + (twohundred) + " twohundred" + Environment.NewLine + (onehundred) + " onehundred" + Environment.NewLine + (fifty) + " fifty" + Environment.NewLine + (twenty) + " twenty");
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CHwS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ccTK.png)

Comment: Are you saying you've been able to implement this as a console application but not in Windows Forms? If so, can you not just change the code in the console application to a method which you can call from the Windows Forms application? That would make it easier to unit test too.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What does it do or not do?

Comment: I did now know that was even possible, to use the Console Application code for Windows Forms. Is that something I can find more information about? And thanks for the answer.

Comment: I added picture for clarity. So the program tells me how much money I get back. I want it also to show me what notes I get back, so for instance: 50 dollarnote, 10, dollarnote etc. Btw I'm not using dollars as the final denomination, just an example.

Comment: I did the program for console application, and it works perfectly.

Comment: You must have skipped the part from your console code where you subtract the amount of the previous change. You're also reusing the variables for both the division and modulo, they should have their own.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm doesn't subtract the highest denomination from the remainder before working out the smaller denominations, so it's actually calculating how many different ways you can make up that total with that one denomination on each line. Once you've decided to pay a 500, you need to work out how to pay the the remaining balance above 500, not the whole balance.